# Why does getegid work for others but not me?

Tags: permissions, group, chmod, chown

I have the following test program:

```
//File: egid_test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int egid =  getegid();
  printf("my effective group is %d\n", egid);
  return 0;
}
```

I run the following series of commands:

```
$ sudo groupadd so_test
$ grep so_test /etc/group
so_test:x:1002:

$ gcc egid_test.c 
$ ./a.out
my effective group is 1000

$ sudo chown :so_test a.out
$ sudo chmod g+s a.out
$ ./a.out
my effective group is 1000
```

I expect the result of the last line to be "my effective group is 1002".  Co-workers get exactly that.  I don't.
Why?  How do I debug what's wrong with my machine and/or configuration?

<sub>(Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)</sub>
**use `sudo groupdel so_test` after you try this to undo group creation

---

Additional Info:

```
$ ls -l a.out
-rwxrwsr-x 1 ashelly so_test 8664 Nov  1 12:17 a.out

$ stat a.out
  File: 'a.out'
  Size: 8664        Blocks: 40         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 33h/51d Inode: 23466994    Links: 1
Access: (2775/-rwxrwsr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    ashelly)   Gid: ( 1002/ so_test)
Access: 2019-11-01 12:17:46.149582840 -0700
Modify: 2019-11-01 12:17:08.949341154 -0700
Change: 2019-11-01 12:38:01.454109385 -0700
 Birth: -

$ df .
Filesystem          1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/home/ashelly/.Private 660427896 45250096 581606988   8% /home/ashelly

$ mount | grep /home/ashelly
/home/.ecryptfs/ashelly/.Private on /home/ashelly type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=<...>,ecryptfs_sig=<...>,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

Is it the 'nosuid' flag on the encryptfs that's causing problems?

Comment: Start off with `ls -l a.out` to ensure that the sgid bit is set. Then us `df .` as an easy way to find where the filesystem you are using is mounted, and then find that mount point in the output of `mount` to see what options you have on the mount.

Comment: Added the output - I'm guessing `nosuid` is a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @icarus, I realize that my home directory, unlike my co-workers',  is mounted from an  ecryptfs encrypted partition, which has the `nosuid` flag set.  (Apparently to patch a [security hole](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2012-3409)).

This prevents the sgid bit from taking effect. If I move my program to `/usr/local/bin`, which doesn't have the `nosuid` flag, it correctly reports the effective group.

At this point, what I need is a good answer to [this question about ecryptfs and nosuid](https://askubuntu.com/q/591708/142515).